# No cuda or opencl on my amd gpu

Tags: gpu, opencl

I have a radeon rx 590 gme card of amd, when i go to prefences there is no cuda hip or open cl all of them says gpu not found or something. so my question is how do i use this card with blender as i am new to the program.

Comment: Well, it is quite simple - if the card does not show up it is most likely not supported by Blender.